# Table Spanning texwidth Using tblr package

Tags: tables, tabularray

I have been looking for a way to get my table to span the \textwidth for my notes. I see it can be done easily using the tabularx package.  I am using the tabularray package and the tblr environment and I am not having any luck.

```
    \begin{tblr}{width=\textwidth,hlines={1pt},vlines={1pt}}
        1. \(\displaystyle\int e^{2x}\cos\big(4x\big)\,dx\)     & 2. \(\displaystyle\int e^{2x}\cos\big(4x\big)\,dx\)  \\[2in]
        3. \(\displaystyle\int e^{2x}\cos\big(4x\big)\,dx\)     & 4. \(\displaystyle\int e^{2x}\cos\big(4x\big)\,dx\)  \\[2in]
    \end{tblr}
```

Here is the snippet of my last try.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some sort of columns which can expand, e.g. one (or more) X columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tblr}{width=\textwidth,hlines={1pt},vlines={1pt},colspec={XX}}
        1. \(\displaystyle\int e^{2x}\cos\big(4x\big)\,dx\)     & 2. \(\displaystyle\int e^{2x}\cos\big(4x\big)\,dx\)  \\[2in]
        3. \(\displaystyle\int e^{2x}\cos\big(4x\big)\,dx\)     & 4. \(\displaystyle\int e^{2x}\cos\big(4x\big)\,dx\)  \\[2in]
    \end{tblr}




\end{document}
```

Comment: Works great! thank you!

Comment: @NickB You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

it is not entirely clear what you after You not declare any columns nor use any features of `tabularray which can help you write your table a lot.

See if the following MWE with of your table code snippet  redesign gives what you after:

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines={1pt}, vline{odd} = {1-Z}{1pt},
                 colspec = {c X[mode=dmath] c X[mode=dmath]},
                 rowsep= 5pt
                 }
1.  &   \int e^{2x}\cos (4x)\,dx    
        & 2.    &   \int e^{2x}\cos (4x) \,dx     \\
3.  &   \int e^{2x}\cos (4x)\,dx 
        & 4.    &   \int e^{2x}\cos (4x) \,dx     \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shows page layout)